# 403 Forbidden cuando intento consumir usando Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc

Estoy intentado consumir un servicio de una página web mediante `RestTemplate`de `Spring`. Sin embargo obtengo el error 403, pero si consumo la URL desde PostMan entonces si me trae la información sin error. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este problema? Les dejo el código del método que utilizo para consumir la URL:

```
 RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    HttpEntity<String> response = rt.exchange(URLRest, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    return response.getBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay ya se que estaba pasando.

Estaba intentando consumir un servicio usando el protocolo HTTP sin embargo el protocolo HTTP no estaba permitido en el servidor, solo permitía HTTPS, entonces PostMan no tenia problema porque automaticamente hacia el cambio de protocolo sin que yo me diera cuenta. Solo tube que cambiar el protocolo y listo.